# Why google crawl not recognise html snapshot instead of angularjs url?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, .htaccess

I have enable `html5mode` for my `Angular JS` application and everything is working fine.

I also have done that html snapshot generating and redirect that snapshot to google crawler when its come to on my site.

`My site is :` http://templatic.net/test/

You can check it by
First open this : http://templatic.net/test/
Then manually check this : `templatic.net/test/?_escaped_fragment_=/`

It will return respected `.html` content, this is all i have done.

So after this i have registered my website in google webmaster tools for indexing purpose and i got indexed my all links.

But i go to webmaster tools and in there when i go to `Fetch as Google` section and i place any of my url then it doesnt return my html snapshot content but it should give me that html content..Right??

This url `http://templatic.net/test/job_category/mobile`
is redirect to this url `http://templatic.net/test/snapshots/job_category/mobile.html` as per google crawler as of `_escaped_fragment_` paramerter

And in my html page i just added one tag just to make sure that google is got my html snapshot while indexing.

So in my webmaster, when i hits fetch as google then it will give me angularjs template which is empty instead of html snapshot, and i dont get it wehter google is recognize my html template section or not.

Here is `Fetch as Google` snapshot : [image]

And in my `.htaccess` file `(For apache)`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*?)\/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/%1.html [R=301,QSD]
```

I dont get it what is wrong i have done after all for this, please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: do you have correct meta tags? Also google got rid of `_escaped_fragment_` requirement at least a year ago

Comment: Google got rid of `_escaped_fragment_` requirement..means?? I have read so many articles regarding this and everyone is working like this and use this so i think its working still...and i think in my problem issue is regarding this parameter..

Comment: Official google webmaster blog reference https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: Ok..so as per this document. Here is stated that `Instead of the _escaped_fragment_ URLs, we'll generally crawl, render, and index the #! URLs` what should i do for indexing of my angularjs application??

Comment: I'm not an expert enough to guide you, just pointing out what I know. I still have apps with `_escaped_fragment_` in them myself but those also require correct meta tags to tell bots they are ajax apps. Now I don't think the meta tags are required but I haven't looked deeply into that part recently

Comment: Yes thats what i'm asking if is there application that is using `_escaped_fragment_` and crawling is working than my website should also  working..right??

Comment: But that blog post from a year ago recommends not using it on new apps. Don't know what to tell you to be honest or whay it isn't being indexed properly.

Comment: OK....can you please provide me any other solutions or help, it would be great for me